# Загрузка и обработка .xlsx на Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

На сервер нужно загрузить файл, пропарсить его, сохранить результат в БД и удалить файл, что бы он не оставался на сервере.
И все с помощью *ajax*.

Как это лучше сделать?

Своя идея:

1. Загрузить файл с использованием *multer*.
2. Далее его пропарсить любым удобным парсером.
3. Удалить файл и сохранить результат.

Как соединить два *middleware*?

Comment: К второму вопросу - согласно [документации](http://expressjs.com/api#app.use), в `.use` и `.METHOD` можно указывать несколько обработчиков через запятую.

Comment: multer умеет загруженный файл в памяти держать, никуда не записывая. Так что можно обойтись без удаления